# window title text size

Tags: android

HI,

I'd like to know what kind of attributes should I use in xml to set the window title text size ?

Answer (score 4):

Following code will help to increase window title bar size and its text size. Hope this will help.

```
<style name="LargeTitleTheme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/titleTextStyle</item>
   </style>

<style name="titleTextStyle" >
    <item name="android:textSize">20dip</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

After declaring styles, apply this style in your application tag or activity tag from App Manifest.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/LargeTitleTheme">
```

Comment: Where is drawable/icon referenced?