# Application title over 2 lines dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

With the help of

[window title text size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824723/window-title-text-size)

I figured out how to let the title-size be more larger. But I want to have it:

1. not on a fixed size e.g. 50dip, but more dependent on the screen
   resolution
2. to switch forth and back between the LargeTitleSize and RegularTitleSize

The main aim should be:

- Depending on the device, it should cover just title with a subtitle (i.e. twice the height of a specific Typeface)
- Let the user decide if two lines or only one is displayed
- Some of the app-titles are designed by default for one-line

Comment: How to auto adjust font size in the action bar http://stackoverflow.com/a/11686495/1012284

Comment: Hm', to what I understand from your link is, that I can use different height for land resp portrait quite easily. But what I fear is, that these values are hard-coded nevertheless. They are not retrieved dynamically. E.g. tablet has more res ==> smaller height then regular phone. Or is there a way to set the styles-attributes dynamically?

Comment: styles you can set for different screens and resolution by giving different values folders.